# Implementing an interface with a property that is derived

Tags: c#, interface

Say if I have

```
interface ISomething
{
    Shape Entity { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Shape
{ }

public class Circle : Shape
{ }

public class Square : Shape
{ }
```

How can I achieve something to the effect of:

```
public class CircleEntity : ISomething
{
    Circle Entity { get; set; }
}

public class SquareEntity: ISomething
{
    Square Entity { get; set; }
}
```

Since `CircleEntity` and `SquareEntity` does not implement `Entity` as type `Shape` exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using [generic interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak.aspx), you can make Entity type variable, which can be defined on derived types.

```
interface ISomething<T> where T:Shape
{
    T Entity { get; set; }
}

public class CircleEntity : ISomething<Circle>
{
    Circle Entity { get; set; }
}

public class SquareEntity: ISomething<Square>
{
    Square Entity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this solves the problem? How do you declare a variable of some interface type, that can hold a CircleEntity or a SquareEntity:

Comment: @FerdinandSwaters, added a bit more description